# VBS script return expected result, how to compare float value?

Tags: vb.net, windows, vbscript

I am getting an interesting result when executing the following VB script.

```
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Set wbemSvc = GetObject("winmgmts://" & "." & "/root/cimv2")
Set biosSet = wbemSvc.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")

For Each biosObj In biosSet
  StdOut.WriteLine "SMBIOSMajorVersion=" & biosObj.SMBIOSMajorVersion
  StdOut.WriteLine "SMBIOSMinorVersion=" & biosObj.SMBIOSMinorVersion
Next

  StdOut.WriteLine "Return value is: " & IsNewBiosVersion

Function IsNewBiosVersion()

  On Error Resume Next
  Set biosSet = wbemSvc.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")

  newBios = 0
  For Each bios In biosSet
    minorFloat = "." & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion
    If bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion > 2 OR (bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion = 2 AND minorFloat >= .6) Then
      newBios = 1
    End If
  Next
  IsNewBiosVersion = newBios

End Function
```

The result is as follow. This looks contradictory since the SMBIOSMinorVersion=4, according to the code logic in the script, the return value should be 0!!!

```
SMBIOSMajorVersion=2
SMBIOSMinorVersion=4
Return value is: 1
```

I ran this same script on another system and got the expected correct result.

```
SMBIOSMajorVersion=2
SMBIOSMinorVersion=4
Return value is: 0
```

So what is the problem here?

New update:

We execute the following script again on the system, and found that the CDbl() function does not convert the string "2.4" to double value correctly, instead it converts it to 24! Looks like the dot "." was lost when converting, what is wrong with this? An bug in CDbl or a violation when use it?

here is the script

```
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
StdOut.WriteLine ""
StdOut.WriteLine "Simple Function to Test BIOS Version"
StdOut.WriteLine ""
Set wbemSvc = GetObject("winmgmts://" & "." & "/root/cimv2")
Set biosSet = wbemSvc.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")

For Each bios In biosSet
  newBios = 0
  StdOut.WriteLine "SMBIOSMajorVersion=" & bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion
  StdOut.WriteLine "SMBIOSMinorVersion=" & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion
  temp = bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion & "." & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion
  StdOut.WriteLine "major dot minor=" & temp

  currentBios = CDbl(bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion & "." & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion)
  StdOut.WriteLine ""
  StdOut.WriteLine "currentBios=" & currentBios
  If currentBios >= 2.6 Then newBios = 1
  StdOut.WriteLine "return value is: " & newBios
Next
```

here is the output

```
Simple Function to Test BIOS Version

SMBIOSMajorVersion=2
SMBIOSMinorVersion=4
major dot minor=2.4

currentBios=24
return value is: 1
```

Comment: Have you checked how many Win32_BIOS objects are being returned into `biosSet`?

Comment: oops, I should put this --> StdOut.WriteLine "Return value is: " & IsNewBiosVersion,  in the loop, but there is no harm, because in both of the systems, only one Win32_BIOS object is return to biosSet

Answer (score 2):

Remove your error handling - it s probably suppressing an issue.

```
On Error Resume Next ' Not a good idea
```

For one thing you are comparing a string to a double in these lines:

```
minorFloat = "." & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion
If bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion > 2 OR (bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion = 2 AND minorFloat >= .6) Then
```

Comment: But how to explain that the return value is 0 on another system?

Comment: Until you compare the data extracted from the system correctly, you cannot account for differences between systems.  For example, from my other comment, another machine might randomly return the real BIOS object and another empty/fake/errorful one, which would overwrite your 'real' result in the loop.

Comment: Sam, looks like the cause is CDbl does not convert "2.4" to a correct value. See my new update above. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just convert the major.minor values to floating-point for your test? You're currently doing two separate tests, with one being a string vs float comparison, which is unusual.

Maybe try this instead?

```
currentBios = CDbl(bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion & "." & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion)

If currentBios >= 2.6 Then newBios = 1
```

You have to be careful comparing floating-point values when math operations are involved but for literal values you'll be fine.

And, as already mentioned, remove `On Error Resume Next` or you may never know why it works on one PC but not another.

Comment: Is it a good idea to compare double value in this way "currentBios >= 2.6" in VB? let me check...

Comment: And as far as I know, the when comparing string with double, the string will be converted to double first, isn't it?

Comment: VBS probably would cast the string to a double, yes. But just to be safe, I would explicitly cast them to the same type. `currentBios`, in my example, is cast to a double so that it can be compared to a literal double (`2.6`). So, we're comparing apples to apples (or doubles to doubles, if you will).

Comment: I keep this line "On Error Resume Next", but replace the comparison codes with your suggested code above, but still get an incorrect return value 1. I am running out of idea again, any idea?

Comment: Bond, we found something interesting, please refer to the description above under the "New update:" field. As you can see, CDbl converts "2.4" to 24! Do you know what is going on here?

Comment: What are your regional settings like? Are you from a country that uses `,` to separate integer from decimal and `.` to group digits? Or, if not, is your PC configured that way? Just create a one-line script that contains the statement: `MsgBox CDbl("2.6")` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, Bond, its locale is Germain. So what should we do to write this code for different locale?

Comment: And I don't quite understand, when this script is executed via some java code, it just returns correct result 2.6, but if it is executed directly, it will converted "2.6" to 26 due to the locale issue. What's going on here?

Comment: Well, German uses `.` where the English use `,`, and vice versa. So if you're using `2.6` and your computer's regional settings are set to German, it's probably treating it like English `2,6`. And the comma is meaningless in English `2,6` so it could be just removing it and giving you `26`. For example, English `1,000` = `1000`. The comma is meaningless. Try `currentBios = CDbl(bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion & "," & bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion)` (note that I changed the decimal to a comma). See if that works.

Comment: Bond, yes, changing decimal to comma will fix the problem on German locale system, but it will bring new issue on English ones. My concern is to write some locale independent code.

Comment: Well, it turns out to be very simple, just adding SetLocale("en-us") at the beginning of of the script would solve the issue. Thanks Bond.